# Implementing an intranet software in which client machines get push updates from a server?

Tags: networking, polling, push

I have an existing .net server infrastructure that resides in a company's intranet. Now for a new feature I'd like normal users (employees) to receive notifications on their machines when specific events occur on the server.

What's the best way to accomplish this?
Polling periodically is a no-go for security reasons. But for a push method to work, we would need a constant connection to the server which gets complicated when there are too many users, disconnections and reconnections need to be handled, etc.
Someone suggested to use a push message broker, which essentially is the "constant connection" approach but the "complicated" stuff is already handled by the broker.

Anyone has an idea how to go about this?

Comment: Look up long polling.

Answer (score 1):

> Pulling periodically is a no-go for security reasons.

Contrarily, I would argue that this "polling" is *exactly* the way you should go.

Your server has little, if any, idea about which clients are running at any point in time and would have to waste a sizeable part of its time maintaining connections to (or even just the information about) each of those clients.
Given that a company will almost certainly have Firewall restrictions in place, your server probably *couldn't* open a "connection" to any of these clients, even if it wanted to.

On the other hand ...

The client [program] knows when it is running, *has* to be able to open a "connection" to the server - otherwise it can't do anything at all - and can easily (and periodically) ask ...

> "Has anything happened I need to know about?"

If the answer comes back "Yes", then the client can fire off a *larger* request to pull back the real Data payload.